# KeyError: "None of [Index(['Company'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby, graphing

I am trying to create a series of graphs for each criteria given a boxplot of the rankings of each company.

My data looks like this:
[Raw Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPYRy.png)

My code is this:

```
import pandas

data= pandas.read_csv(r"C:\Users\Steven\Desktop\ELNResults2.csv", nrows=(145))
criteriadata= data.groupby("Criteria")
criteriadata.boxplot(column=['Company'])
```

I am getting this error:

```
KeyError: "None of [Index(['Company'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"
```

However, when I run this.

```
print(data.columns)
```

I get this:

```
Index(['Company', 'Criteria', 'Ranking'], dtype='object')
```

So to me this looks like Company is in the columns??

I am a beginning user so I am still learning. As a side note I don't like how all the tutorials I have found use a data set created in script like linspace as opposed to importing datasets. I have found that does not mimic what happens in real life, working in the biotech industry I have found 99.9% of all data comes as a csv.

Comment: please post your data, `df.to_dic()` etc

Answer (score 0):

When using the `boxplot` method on a pandas groupby, the `column` argument refers to the column in the DataFrame that holds the numerical data upon which the distribution(s) will be drawn. I believe what you look after is to pass `"Company"` to the `by` argument instead of passing it to the `column` argument, whereas `"Ranking"` should be the column name that should be passed to the `column` argument (although in this case, using the `column` argument is irrelevant since you are left with only one column holding numerical data). It can be summarised as follows:

`criteriadata.boxplot(column="Ranking", by="Company")`